# How to get MySite navigation bar to show up on a sub-site that is also using the mysite.master page

Tags: sharepoint-2010, mysite

We have a created a subsite to the SharePoint 2010 Mysite (used blank site) called "home".  This site uses the mysite.master master page.  The problem is the top link (navigation) bar from MySite is not showing up on the subsite...  Any ideas?

If I open the home site in Share Point Designer - the navigation bar does show up... But not in the browser...

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Terry

Answer (score 0):

We ran into this too. I believe this is a product bug. At any rate, the problem has to do with the MySiteNavigation feature not being activated on the site. Unfortunately, this feature doesn't show up within the list of features on the site (ManageFeatures.aspx). You have to programmatically activate the feature. I believe you can do this with the Enable-SPFeature cmdlet.

As a work around we are contemplating creating an event receiver to activate this feature for all sub sites of a my site.

Comment: Thanks Doug!! I will play around with this and let you know what I find

Comment: Thanks again Doug.  We were able to turn it on using the PowerShell.  Here are the commands we ran:

Comment: $webAppsFeatureId = $(Get-SPFeature -limit all | where {$_.displayname -eq "MySiteNavigation"}).Id 
Get-SPSite -limit ALL |foreach{Enable-SPFeature $webAppsFeatureId -url $_.URL }